# how C# use Continuation passing style and Aggregate

Tags: c#

Example 1 :

```
void Main()
{
    var seq = new int[] {-4,-3,0,1,2,3,4,};
    var res = seq.Aggregate(0, (a,s) => s >= 0? a+1 : a-1);
}
```

Anyone can explain what is `0, (a,s)=> s >= 0` ? a+1 : a-1 means in the `Aggregate()`?

Example 2 :

```
void Main()
{
    Func<int,int> H = null;
    H = n=> n<=1 ? 1 : 2*H(n-1)+1;
    int x = H(3) + H(5);
}
```

And what does n=>n<=1?1:2*H(n-1)+1 means? why there is a "=>" in left of n and a "<=" in the right of n? and what does ":" symbol means? What does the "?" mark means?

Comment: It may be better to use samples with readable names when learning... Also consider reading about each of basic operators in C# before digging into lambda... I.e. asking "what ? means in C#" does will only bring you downvotes...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In `seq.Aggregate(0,(a,s)=>s>=0?a+1:a-1);` the first parameter (0) is a seed value. The second parameter is a lambda expression that specifies a delegate (a method) that will be run for each element in the sequence. The method `Aggregate` will start from the seed (in this case 0) and add to it the results obtained from processing each element in the sequence. Here is a longer equivalent form that may give you a better idea of what is going on:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    var seq = new int[] { -4, -3, 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, };
    var res = seq.Aggregate(0, (a, s) => Calculate(a, s));
}

private static int Calculate(int a, int s)
{
    int returnValue = s >= 0 ? a + 1 : a - 1;
    return returnValue;
}
```

I suggest you place breakpoints in the code (either in the code in your sample or in my second more verbose form) to better figure out what is going on.

In the second example `Func<int,int>` is a delegate type. In line
`Func<int, int> H = null;`
you are declaring a variable H that is a method delegate type that takes one int input parameter and returns an int result. On the next line:
`H = n => n <= 1 ? 1 : 2 * H(n - 1) + 1;`
you are assigning a lambda expression to H (in effect you are assigning a delegate method to H). On the next line:
`int x = H(3) + H(5);`
you assign to x an expression where you invoke H twice. See below is a more verbose equivalent form that may explain better what is going on.
Note that this particular implementation for H is a recursive method. This aspect as well is easier to see in the more verbose form. Note that method `Calculate` calls itself:

```
private static void Main(string[] args)
{
    Func<int, int> H = null;
    H = Calculate;    // Note that Calculate is not invoked here yet

    int x = H(3) + H(5);
}

private static int Calculate(int input)
{
    int output = input <= 1 ? 1 : 2 * Calculate(input - 1) + 1;
    return output;
}
```

or

```
private static int Calculate(int input)
{
    if (input <= 1)
    {
        return 1;
    }
    else
    {
        return 2 * Calculate(input - 1) + 1;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Starting with a sum of `0`, iterate through `seq`, and call `(a, s) => s == 0 ? a + 1 : a - 1` on each element, adding the result of the call to the sum. So, the first call will add the value of the first element + 1 to the sum, and all other calls will add the value of the element - 1 to the sum.

As for the other questions, look up lambda expressions and ternary statement.